# Google Optimize JS - jQuery error

Tags: asynchronous, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I tried optymalize my site with PageSpeed Insights.
This Google tool shows me error : 
`"Eliminate blocking rendering JavaScript code".`
I moved all script code from head at the end of the page.
Error was fixed, but now I get in console error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined  $(document).ready(function() {
```

The reason of error is probably several js codes in body section. 
How I can eliminate this? 
Do I must move code from body at the end of the page or there are other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependency problem, something is using jQuery (probably) before it's initiated. Is the jQuery loader script still in header, or above the script that uses $(document).ready()?

Some scripts are asynchronous and some are not. Keep this in mind also, because if jQuery for instance is loaded asynchronous and is above your script, and your script is loaded synchronous, it might not matter. Your script would still be loaded before the async script has finished loading.

There is no need to place asynchronous script in the bottom of the body - and sometimes PageSpeed is not correct in it's assumptions about block rendering scripts. You can also try the "defer" HTML attribute on the script tags you want to defer after DOM is ready.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer